# Is SMIL dead, or possibly just pining for the fjords?

Tags: smil

Is SMIL ([Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronized_Multimedia_Integration_Language)) dead for modern applications?

Is there a standardized format for combining media that has replaced it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the lack of response and the age of most resources on the web, it seems safe to assume that SMIL is not actively being pursued for new development.

Comment: Working on sending MMS that requires SMIL.  Trying to find references, authoring resources, and players for debugging (especially on Windows) is a bit depressing.

Comment: here is an excellent article on alternatives to SMIL: https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/